# Do I need to check for null input when implementing java.util.function.Function<T,R>

Tags: java, java-8

When using java8 stream API

```
.stream().map(mapper)
```

is it neccessary in the mapper's `apply(T t)` method implemented as `java.util.function.Function<T,R>`  check for `null` input `t`? Or is it guaranteed that the `apply(T t)` method is never called with `null` argument even when my `stream()`-ed `Collection` contains`null`s?

In another words,

```
    .stream().map(mapper)
```

allows `null` values to be passed into `apply(T t)` and does not throws `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on whether you expect a `null` as an input.  In general you will want to avoid using `null` is a stream (or throwing check exceptions).  You can do

```
list.stream()
    .filter(x -> x != null)
    .... do more
```

Note if you do

```
Stream.of("hi", null).forEach(System.out::println);
```

will print

```
hi
null
```

See http://ideone.com/eoQ3so

Comment: or `.filter(Objects::nonNull)`

Comment: Well, more something along the line Stream.of("hi", null).map(Function.identity()).forEach(System.out::println);

Comment: My question was probably not very well formulated, but I did not ask whether is is suitable to put nulls into Collection or stream. Neither I wanted to ask how to filter them out. Rather, my question was, if I happen to do so, do these nulls arrive in Function.apply(...)? And therefore I need to handle them there? Or are they considered invalid input by the stream/map machinery and thus never come up to Function.apply(...)? Of course I know the answer by now.